# Сдвигается меню при наведении на ссылку

Tags: jquery, html, css

Код - http://jsfiddle.net/FPrp9/3/

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на ссылку в меню, следующие за ним пункты оставались неподвижными? Можно на jQuery, но если возможно, то лучше на CSS. Пробовал играть с отступами, но что-то безрезультатно, не могу понять, что увеличивается, когда ссылка становится жирной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bMw4X/

http://jsfiddle.net/sPwN6/ - без привязке к ширине

Comment: Спасибо, но есть какой-то другой вариант? Не хотелось бы жестко привязываться к ширине ссылки.

Comment: обновил добавил второй вариант в ответ

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!